# Apportion with negative value

Tags: linear-algebra

There are two scenarios A and B.

Scenario A: Tax authority T assesses the incomes of Person J and Person B separately. J gets a tax refund of € 104.43 from T. B needs to pay additional taxes in the amount of € 2882.80 to T.

Scenario B: T assesses the incomes of J and B jointly. The couple together gets a tax refund of € 1507.54.

J and B are allowed to tell T whether they like to be taxed under scenario A or B. They choose for scenario B because it is more beneficial to them jointly.

J and B want to split the tax refund of scenario B but did not find a method how to apportion the € 1507.54 while considering the ratios of tax refund/payment in scenario A.

I would like to know how to apportion the tax refund on a mathematical basis. If B would also receive a tax refund of € 104.43 in scenario B. Then I could split the € 1507.54 in two halfs. But B's "negative" tax refund in scenario A puzzles me.

The "Couples Subsidy" in scenario B comes from the average income of the couple being taxed, and by legislative law, the tax grows exponentially when the income increases. If there is a income gap between J and B then the average income of the couple will reduce the joint tax. If J and B had the same income each, then there would be no tax reduction as the average income of the couple remains the same with the income of each person.

J took a year off work to complete his studies, J had no income for that tax year, in such J reduced the average income of the couple by 50 %. J did not rely on B's financial support but used his own savings.

Can you please help?

Comment: Haven't you asked exactly this question previously?  What is your response to the comments that were made then?

Comment: I responded to the comments with more information (now included above), but there were no answers to my response so I thought people lost track of my last thread and I started this thread.